# std::unique_ptr with std::map

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers, stdmap

I have a `std::map` where the key is `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` and the value is `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` where `Foo` and `Bar` are very different classes from a third-party library. I am using this `std::map` object as an in-memory cache.

I am wondering what the best way of inserting a new entry into this map will be and then returned from a method, given that the `Bar` passed into the `std::unique_ptr` will already be constructed?

I currently have the following:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

    const Bar* TryGetBarValue(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo)
    {
        auto it = _cache.find(foo);

        if(it == _cache.end())
        {
            Bar bar = ThirdPartLibrary::CreateBar();
            _cache.emplace(foo, std::make_unique<Bar>(bar));
            return _cache.rbegin()->second.get();
        }

        //return result as raw ptr from unique_ptr
        return it->second.get();
    }

private:
    std::map<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::unique_ptr<Bar>> _cache;
}
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answer provided by Quentin, this is now my implementation:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:

    const Bar* TryGetBarValue(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo)
    {
        auto it = _cachedImages.find(texture);

        if (it != _cachedImages.end())
        {
            return it->second.get();
        }

        return _cachedImages.emplace(
                std::move(texture), 
                std::make_unique<sf::Image>(texture->copyToImage())
            ).first->second.get(); 
        }

private:
    std::map<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, std::unique_ptr<Bar>> _cache;
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Not directly related but have you created hash functions for Foo and Bar ?

Comment: Can that `unique_ptr` be null? Does it really need to share ownership of `Foo`? shared_ptrs are a sign of poor design in 99% of cases.

Comment: As an aside, `return _cache.rbegin()->second.get();` is likely wrong, since in a `std::map` elements get inserted into sorted order according to `std::less`. So a newly inserted element is unlikely to be at the `rbegin()` location.

Comment: Trying to be constructive here, I really don't see the point of return a raw pointer, if you are using a unique, well, for uniqueness. If you need to share access then use a shared altogether and bridge them with whatever class you need. If you want to ensure uniqueness, then instead of raw, move/erase?

Comment: @Ælex "unique" refers to the numer of owners, not observers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return _cache.rbegin()->second.get();` does not do what you want, as `std::map` does not *append* elements but *sorts* them. However `emplace` returns an iterator to what it just inserted, so you only need:

```
return _cache.emplace(foo, std::make_unique<Bar>(bar))->first->second.get();
```

Or even, since you don't actually need to store and copy the `Bar`, and you can also sacrifice `foo`:

```
return _cache.emplace(
    std::move(foo),
    std::make_unique<Bar>(ThirdPartLibrary::CreateBar())
)->first->second.get();
```

I'd also personally flip the `(it == _cache.end())` condition to make it an early return, but that's just a matter of taste.

Otherwise, what you have looks good to me.

Comment: The only thing I can see is possibly doing `std::make_unique<...>(std::move(bar))` in case the move constructor can do better than the copy constructor.

Comment: @SirGuy indeed, added that to the answer :)

Comment: accepted this answer, it is exactly what i was looking for and thanks for the heads up about rbegin(), i'll change that to use your suggestion.

Comment: The redundant copy applies to the key as well. Moving `foo` would be sufficient. In the case of shared pointer we know that move is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this as c++14, but for posterity I'll add a C++17 version:

```
const Bar* TryGetBarValue(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo)
{
    struct DelayedBar
    {
        operator std::unique_ptr<Bar>() const { return std::make_unique<Bar>(thirdpartyLibrary::CreateBar()); }
    };
    return _cache.try_emplace(std::move(foo), DelayedBar()).first->second.get();
}
```

The `try_emplace` function will emplace its arguments if the map doesn't already contain that key. If the key already exists, no object is constructed. In either case an iterator to that key/value pair is returned. This function avoids the double lookup involved when you do `find` -> `emplace/insert`.

In our case we can't simply pass the arguments of `try_emplace` along so I've tried to be clever in delaying the construction of the object using this `DelayedBar` class. It only calls `CreateNewBar` when trying to cast to a `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` which only happens when `try_emplace` is trying to construct the object.

I have compiled this with GCC 8.2, Clang 7.0.0 and MSVC 19.16 (all via Compiler Explorer) and it compiles okay.