# how to move unique_ptr object between two STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;


struct Task {
    char t;
    int cnt;
    Task(char ch, int cnt):t(ch), cnt(cnt){};
};
struct CompTask {
    bool operator() (const unique_ptr<Task>& a, const unique_ptr<Task>& b) {
        return a->cnt < b->cnt;
    }
};
class Schedule {
public:
    int schedule() {
        unordered_map<unique_ptr<Task>, int> sleep_q;
        priority_queue<unique_ptr<Task>, vector<unique_ptr<Task>>, CompTask> ready_q; // max heap
        ready_q.push(std::make_unique<Task>('A', 1));

        auto& ptr = ready_q.top();
        //sleep_q.insert({ptr, 1}); // compile error 
        sleep_q.insert({std::move(ptr), 1}); // compile error 
        // some other code...
        
        return 1;
    }
};
int main() {
    return 0;

}
// error:
cpp:38:17: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
        sleep_q.insert({std::move(ptr), 1}); // compile error 
        ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Programming context:
I had a task class and the program attempts to simulate the task scheduling (which involves moving a task back and forth between a ready queue and a sleep queue).
I have two std containers for ready queue and sleep queue respectively, the priority_queue has value type `unique_ptr<Task>`, the other is
unorder_map (sleep queue) whose key is also `unique_ptr<Task>`. I had trouble moving the unique_ptr object from priorty_queue to unordered_map (shown in the code).

My questions are:
(1) how to insert an item into the unordered_map, I had compilation errors on doing that.
(2) in the problem context, which type of "pointer" would be preferred? `unique_ptr<Task>, shared_ptr<Task>, or just Task*`

Comment: Please list the compiler error(s).  An `unordered_map` requires that the key can be hashed, if not, you have to provide the hash function as a template argument.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the default Hash functor supports unique_ptr:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash. As per your suggestion, I had added the compilation error info.

Comment: For (1), did you try `emplace` instead of `insert`?  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828756/stdunique-ptr-with-stdmap)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  tried but still with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be lack of move functionality out of `std::priority_queue<>`. You can go around it using `const_cast`, though in rare cases it might cause undefined behavior (when stored element type is `const`).

```
    int schedule() {
        unordered_map<unique_ptr<Task>, int> sleep_q;
        priority_queue<unique_ptr<Task>, vector<unique_ptr<Task>>, CompTask> ready_q; // max heap                                                                                                     
        ready_q.push(std::make_unique<Task>('A', 1));

        unique_ptr<Task> ptr = 
                std::move(const_cast<unique_ptr<Task>&>(ready_q.top()));
        //                ^ Here. priority_queue::top() returns `const&`.
        ready_q.pop(); // remove moved element from priority_queue
        sleep_q.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(ptr), 1));                                                                                                                          
        // some other code...                                                                                                                                                                         

        return 1;
    }
```

Reference: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149745/7697209)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the root of the error.  Seems we should put `ready_q.pop()` **after** `sleep_q.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(ptr), 1)); `, otherwise there is an runtime error. Have you noticed that?

Comment: @kz28 Oh you're so right. Keeping a reference to an element that then gets popped is undefined behavior. This should work now. The `unique_ptr` element now gets directly moved to `ptr` and then popped.

Comment: @kz28 Note another change. `std::move` is more idiomatic than using `const_cast` to change lvalue to rvalue reference.

Answer (score -1):

To move a `unique_ptr` between std containers requires destroying one `unique_ptr` (stored within the first std container) and passing the backing data to a new `unique_ptr`. This can be done with `std::move`. However, it's usually easier to use a `shared_ptr`. Which avoids the problem by allowing `shared_ptr` point to the same task to be in two std containers simultaneously. Even if just for a moment.

However, since you could have multiple `shared_ptr` objects pointing the same task the `shared_ptr` wouldn't work to uniquely identify the task. To do that, I would recommend creating a Task Id for each task. A simple integer would work for this, as long as you guarantee it's unique to that task. An integer task Id would work well with a map since the Id could be used as the key.